# Odd cookie set by WordPress installed in a sub directory

Tags: wordpress

I want to install & configure my WordPress site in `/journal` like:

https://example.com/journal/

After my installation, when I try to access `/wp-admin`, they say cookie settings haven't been configured within my browser and I fail to log in. When I hit `curl`:

```
$ curl -I localhost/journal/wp-login.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 12:02:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Amazon Linux 2) PHP/7.2.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.0
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/journal/journal/; secure
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I suppose the cookie path being `/journal/journal/` is the reason I can't log in properly. What kind of additional configuration is needed to set my cookies properly?

Comment: Do you have `COOKIEPATH` or `SITECOOKIEPATH` set in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: Additionally, is your site and home URL correct in the `options` table?  If not, that could be a factor.